# C: Terminate a called function that is stuck in infinite loop from main

Tags: c, infinite-loop

Let's assume I've got the following main in a c file

```
int f();
int main(){
     //terminate f() if in infinite loop
     return f();
}
```

and then a separate c file that could potentially hold the following:

```
int f() {
    for(;;) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to detect that the function f() is in an infinite loop and terminate it's execution from within the main function?

EDIT:
I need this functionality as I am writing a testbench where the function called could potentially have an infinite loop - that's what I am checking for in the end. Therefore, I cannot modify f() in anyway. I'm also in a Linux environment.

Comment: No, there's no standard C way to do this. There are OS-specific ways to set a signal that goes off after a specified amount of time or CPU time, and the handler for the signal could exit.

Comment: No, there is no way to definitively determine if `f()` contains an infinite loop nor is there a way to terminate it within `main()` as you have written it here.  _However_, have you looked into threads?  You could start `f()` in another thread and set a timeout in `main()` that terminates the thread if it hasn't completed by the time the time out is reached.

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why you'd want this?

Comment: try to use  something like WDT : )

Comment: I cannot solve the infinite loop as I am writing a testbench where the function called could potentially have an infinite loop - that's what I am checking for. Also I'm on Linux, so as suggested in a comment to an answer below, I'll look into pthreads.

Comment: Well, terminating the process from another thread works fine:)

Comment: I provided a simple example to get you started.  You'll definitely want to look into pthreads a little more in depth, but my example should get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [there is no way to definitively determine if a function contains an infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

However, we can make a few assumptions to detect a potential infinite loop and exit a program gracefully within the program (e.g. we don't have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).  This method is common in several testing frameworks used in JS.  Basically, we set some arbitrary time limit for a function to complete in.  If the function does not complete within that time limit, we assume it will not complete and we throw an error.

In C/C++ you could implement this with pthreads if you're on a Unix system.  In Windows, you would use `windows.h`.  I only have experience with `pthreads`, so I'll show a simple example of how you might get this working using pthreads.

```
#include <pthread.h>  // Load pthread
#include <signal.h>   // If f() does not exit, we will need this library to send it a signal to kill itself.
#include <stdbool.h>  // You could use an int or char.
#include <stddef.h>   // Defines NULL
#include <unistd.h>   // Defines sleep()

bool testComplete;   // Has the test completed?

/**
 * The function being tested.
 */
void f() {
    while(true);
}

/**
 * This method handles executing the test.  This is the function pthread will
 * use as its start routine.  It takes no arguments and returns no results.
 * The signature is required for pthread_create().
 */
void *runTest(void *ptr) {
    testComplete = false;

    f();

    testComplete = true;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t testThread;

    pthread_create(&testThread, NULL, runTest, NULL);  // Create and start the new thread.  It will begin executing runTest() eventually.

    sleep(5);      // Give it 5 seconds to complete (this should be adjusted or could even be made dynamic).

    if(testComplete) {
        // Test completed successfully.
        pthread_join(testThread, NULL);
    } else {
        // The test did not exit successfully within the time limit.  Kill it and you'll probably what to provide some feedback here.
        pthread_kill(testThread, SIGPIPE); // There are other signals, but this one cannot be ignored or caught.
    }
}
```

To compile this, you would need to execute `gcc your_filename.c -o output_filename -lpthread`.

If you expect the program to run on both Unix and Windows systems, you may want to consider making some unified interface for accessing threads and then adapting the OS-specific interfaces to your interface.  It will make things a little simpler, especially when expanding this library.

Answer (score 2):

You could call `f()` in a different thread and have main time-out `f()` when it reaches a certain limit. However, I don't think this is practical and you should really work on solving the infinite loop first.

Comment: Just suggested that in a comment.  Good idea, if I do say so myself :)

Comment: I cannot solve the infinite loop as I am writing a testbench where the function called could potentially have an infinite loop - that's what I am checking for. I've never used threads before. How would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

On a Posix system (Linux, MacOS) you can schedule an alarm in the future with `setitimer()` before calling the function. Signal SIGALRM will be delivered to the process after the specified  delay. Make sure that your program has the signal handler, you should register it with `sigaction()` before starting the timer.

When the signal handler takes control after the signal is raised, you may get out if the offending loop with `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `f()` the way you showed (from `main`) then at that point the main context is in `f`, not `main` and therefore you cannot "check `f` from `main`".

What you can try is calling `f()` from a separate thread and check whether that thread has finished within specified time limit. However I'm not sure about practicality of this. While I don't know what you really plan to do in that function, n some cases you may stop this function from executing at the point where it did soemthing that requires cleaning up. One example that comes to mind is it calling `malloc` but but being able to call `free` at the point where you interrupt it.

Honestly, if there's a certain requirement about the time in which given function has to finish, just put that check within the function itself and return `false` to indicate it didn't finish successfully.